# Flex 4.5 TextArea height to match .text height?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Is it possible to have the textarea height be dynamically adjusted to the .text in a spark TextArea?

Answer (score -1):

Got this while googling for the same query

http://polygeek.com/2342_flex_setting-a-textareas-height-to-its-contentheight